# Getting [WinError 10054] error while trying to fetch data through panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')

df.head()
```

When I run the code, I get a following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Can you visit that url in your browser? Maybe GitHub is restricted or blocked in your geographical area.

Comment: No, its not restricted or blocked in my area and also i am able to open the url in my browser.

Comment: Hi Richard,you can open below link if u r facing any issue....https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv